# Postgres cannot create database but can create a user

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I am using Ubuntu Linux. I am trying to use Postgres as database. It is doing fine when I created a user:

```
CREATE USER username;
```

But when I try to create a database, it returns nothing:

```
CREATE DATABASE databasename;
```

What is happening with my Postgres?

[image]

```
 datid | datname  | pid  | leader_pid | usesysid | usename  | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          |         state_change          | wait_event_type |     wait_event      | state  | backend_xid | backend_xmin | query_id |              query              |         backend_type
-------+----------+------+------------+----------+----------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+--------------+----------+---------------------------------+------------------------------
       |          | 8237 |            |          |          |                  |             |                 |             | 2022-02-02 13:00:47.683187+07 |                               |                               |                               | Activity        | AutoVacuumMain      |        |             |              |          |                                 | autovacuum launcher
       |          | 8239 |            |       10 | postgres |                  |             |                 |             | 2022-02-02 13:00:47.70127+07  |                               |                               |                               | Activity        | LogicalLauncherMain |        |             |              |          |                                 | logical replication launcher
 13726 | postgres | 8329 |            |       10 | postgres | psql             |             |                 |          -1 | 2022-02-02 13:08:52.250244+07 | 2022-02-02 13:09:10.651383+07 | 2022-02-02 13:09:10.651383+07 | 2022-02-02 13:09:10.651393+07 | Lock            | object              | active |             |          740 |          | CREATE DATABASE kong;           | client backend
 13726 | postgres | 8313 |            |       10 | postgres | psql             |             |                 |          -1 | 2022-02-02 13:04:57.265085+07 | 2022-02-02 13:10:40.097817+07 | 2022-02-02 13:10:40.097817+07 | 2022-02-02 13:10:40.09782+07  |                 |                     | active |             |          740 |          | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity; | client backend
       |          | 8235 |            |          |          |                  |             |                 |             | 2022-02-02 13:00:47.664058+07 |                               |                               |                               | Activity        | BgWriterHibernate   |        |             |              |          |                                 | background writer
       |          | 8234 |            |          |          |                  |             |                 |             | 2022-02-02 13:00:47.654713+07 |                               |                               |                               | Activity        | CheckpointerMain    |        |             |              |          |                                 | checkpointer
       |          | 8236 |            |          |          |                  |             |                 |             | 2022-02-02 13:00:47.673631+07 |                               |                               |                               | Activity        | WalWriterMain       |        |             |              |          |                                 | walwriter
(7 rows)

(END)
```

and for the pg_locks

```
  locktype  | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction | pid  |       mode       | granted | fastpath |           waitstart
------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+------+------------------+---------+----------+-------------------------------
 relation   |    13726 |    12290 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/17               | 8313 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t        |
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 7/17       |               |         |       |          | 7/17               | 8313 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t        |
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 3/15       |               |         |       |          | 3/15               | 8329 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t        |
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 6/12       |               |         |       |          | 6/12               | 8335 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t        |
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 5/3        |               |         |       |          | 5/3                | 8266 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t        |
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 4/1        |               |         |       |          | 4/1                | 8264 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t        |
 object     |        0 |          |      |       |            |               |    1262 |     1 |        0 | 6/12               | 8335 | RowExclusiveLock | f       | f        | 2022-02-02 13:09:30.561821+07
 object     |        0 |          |      |       |            |               |    1262 |     1 |        0 | 3/15               | 8329 | ShareLock        | f       | f        | 2022-02-02 13:09:10.651571+07
 object     |        0 |          |      |       |            |               |    1262 |     1 |        0 | 4/1                | 8264 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f        |
 relation   |        0 |     1262 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 3/15               | 8329 | AccessShareLock  | t       | f        |
 object     |        0 |          |      |       |            |               |    1262 |     1 |        0 | 5/3                | 8266 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | f        |
(11 rows)

(END)
```

Database info

```
postgres=# \l
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   |  Size   | Tablespace |                Description
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |                       | 8529 kB | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 8377 kB | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            |
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 8529 kB | pg_default | default template for new databases
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            |
(3 rows)

postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 kong      |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

postgres=#
```

Comment: While the `CREATE DATABASE` statement is hanging, open a second database connection and run `SELECT * FROM pg_locks;` and `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;`. [Edit] the question and add the results there (as formatted text, not as a screenshot).

Comment: it returns LOCK in wait_event_type when creating a user returns client. What does it means?

Comment: I think I told you what to do.

Comment: ah sorry, there you go @LaurenzAlbe .

Comment: Thanks. So it seems that processes 8264 and 8266 hold a lock on the `template1` database. Funny that I don't see them in `pg_stat_activity`. Do you have connections to `template1`?

Comment: i actually just fresh installed this postgres, i dont know if i have one or not. how to check if it connects to another db? i just add the database info in the post.

Comment: Well, then I guess that you have just a slow and buggy file system, and you didn't wait long enough.

Comment: i solved it by installing the old version of pg. i tried version 12 and now its working perfectly. Thank you for the help!! much appreciate your time @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling the pg to its old version (was installed 14, downgrade to 12 and it solved). Thanks to everyone here who helped me

Answer (score 0):

Using the same database name and user is not good practice. This may result in various errors.

When you call the command

```
CREATE DATABASE databaseName;
```

PostgreSql creates a database. This may take some time. After creating the database, you will receive a message:

```
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=#
```

Comment: update , when i tried to wait long enough, it returns postgres=# CREATE DATABASE kong;
WARNING:  could not flush dirty data: Function not implemented. It didnt run successfully

Comment: Looks like you are using some "operating system" that does not work properly. Your database was created (a warning is no error), but don't use this system for anything but playing.

Comment: @ioiofadhil try restarting postgres and run the command again.
At Ubuntu shell: `sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: hmm i see, so the ubuntu is the prob behind all this. Okay thanks for the help @LaurenzAlbe.

i tried it but still same result. @ onluck

Comment: @ioiofadhil: might not be Ubuntu, but the file system you are using.